# how to detect class variable changes into your component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, async-await, vue-component

I have a problem, I put an API call into a class to get DB data instead of calling it into my page directly but now I have to get the changes of varible state (I use that variable to display something when I have no data).

My Page:

```
import TripsDataService from '../services/trips_data_service'
export default {...
methods: {
async getClientsData () {
      await TripsDataService.getTripsDataForDashboard()
      this.serviceData.tripsInfo = TripsDataService.tripsInfo // that variable bring the API data fine
      this.timeUp = TripsDataService.timeUp // but that still allows false
      console.log(this.timeUp)
    }
```

TripDataService class:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { Notify } from 'quasar'

class TripDataService {
  totalGainClaster = []
  tripsInfo = []
  timeUp = false

  async getAll (payload) {
    this.totalGainClaster = []
    return axios.get('/parse/classes/Trip', { params: payload })
      .then((response) => {
        return response.data.results.map((element) => {
              const index = this.totalGainClaster.map(x => x.driverId.objectId).indexOf(element.driver.objectId)
              index === -1 ? this.totalGainClaster.push({ total: element.price, driverId: element.driver }) : this.totalGainClaster[index].total += element.price
          return element
        })
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        Notify.create({ message: e, position: 'top-left' })
      })
  }

  getTripsDataForDashboard () {
    axios.get('/parse/classes/Trip',
      {
        params: { where: { isCancelled: false } }
      }
    )
      .then((response) => {
        response.data.results.forEach(element => {
          const object = {
            isCancelled: element.isCancelled,
            isFinished: element.isFinished,
            objectId: element.objectId,
            updatedAt: element.updatedAt,
            price: element.price || 0,
            driverId: element.driver?.objectId || null
          }
          this.tripsInfo.push(object)
          this.timeUp = true
        })
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        Notify.create({ message: 'Erreur de connexion', position: 'bottom-right' })
        this.timeUp = true
      })
  }


export default new TripDataService()
```

edit: I have added all TripDataService class

Comment: There is no `export` shown in *TripDataService* but `import TripsDataService` would not work without it?

Comment: there is export of new instace of class `export default new TripDataService()`

Comment: It would be helpful to edit your post to show the class:  export, constructor, etc, so that others can test it

Comment: @Dan ok Done!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the axios promise in `getTripsDataForDashboard`:

```js
getTripsDataForDashboard () {
    return axios.get('/parse/classes/Trip',
    ...
}
```

The async call was not returning a promise so it seems impossible that `TripsDataService.tripsInfo` had the correct info from this code alone.  Maybe if the axios URL is local?  But in that case it would make more sense to `import` the data instead of using axios.  Anyway, this should fix it.